# Show that $x(t) = e^{- \gamma t} \cos(\omega t) x(0)$ is the solution a diffusion equation.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, probability-theory, solution-verification, stochastic-differential-equations

I am working through [Kurt Jacob's Stochastic Processes for Physicists](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/stochastic-processes-for-physicists/A4DA560863F148D920B6A3165996D5D7) and came across a question I am unsure about on linear diffusions.

> The equation for the damped harmonic oscillator is
>
> \begin{align} m \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 x}{\mathrm{d}^2 t}  + 2 \gamma m
>  \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{d} t} + kx = 0 . \end{align}
>
> Assume that $\gamma < \sqrt{k/m}$, in which the resonator is said to
> be "under-damped". Show that
>
> $$ x(t) = e^{- \gamma t} \cos(\omega t) x(0)$$
>
> is the solution to the equation above, and find the expression for the
> frequency $\omega$ in terms of $m,k$ and $\gamma$.
>
> (pg 24 Question 1)

Comment: Compute the first and second derivative of the given $x(t)$ and replace them in the equation. Then simplify it to show that the equality holds.

Comment: @AugSB It does not. You have a term with $\sin(\omega t)$. You can account for this by adding a phase.

Comment: @Andrei Unless I've differentiated incorrectly, the $\sin(\omega t)$ term vanishes.

Comment: @mattos Sorry, my mistake. You are right. I've missed a sign.

Comment: Just plug in the expression for the solution. What do you get? Note that it's not the only solution. You should get one with $\sin$ as well

Comment: You dropped the minus in the exponent, that's your mistake.

Comment: Thanks my answer is still wrong with the minus in the exponent. I then get $\left(3 \gamma^{2} m \cos{\left (\omega t \right )} - 4 \gamma \omega m \sin{\left (\omega t \right )} - \omega^{2} m \cos{\left (\omega t \right )} + k x e^{\gamma t}\right) e^{- \gamma t}$

Comment: Redo the computation from the beginning.

Comment: I see what you mean. I am redoing it now.

Comment: I still have not found the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An explanation "keeping in mind" for the students:

The equation for your damped oscillator is:
$$m \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 x}{\mathrm{d}^2 t}  + 2 \gamma m \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{d} t} + kx = 0$$
To show that $$ x(t) = e^{- \gamma t} \cos(\omega t) x(0)$$  is the solution to the above equation, recall the fact that $x(t)$  can only be a solution to the equation if it satisfies the differential equation. I am not solving the differential equation as it has already been solved previously. If you want to solve this equation there are many ways of doing it, from complex exponentials to Laplace transform and what not. Usually sometimes we also assume functions of some specific form to be the solution and carry on the analysis to find it.

Calculate the derivatives :
$$ x(t) =  x(0)\ e^{- \gamma t} \cos(\omega t)$$
$$ x'(t) = x(0)[- \gamma  e^{- \gamma t} \cos(\omega t) - \omega e^{- \gamma t} \sin(\omega t)]$$
$$ x''(t) = x(0)[ \gamma^2  e^{- \gamma t} \cos(\omega t) +\gamma \omega e^{- \gamma t} \sin(\omega t) - \omega^2e^{- \gamma t} \cos (\omega t) + \gamma \omega e^{- \gamma t} \sin(\omega t)]$$

Now, put $x(t)$ in the differential equation to get:
$$m x(0)[ \gamma^2  e^{- \gamma t} \cos(\omega t) +\gamma \omega e^{- \gamma t} \sin(\omega t) - \omega^2e^{- \gamma t} \cos (\omega t) + \gamma \omega e^{- \gamma t} \sin(\omega t)] + 2 x(0)[- \gamma  e^{- \gamma t} \cos(\omega t) - \omega e^{- \gamma t} \sin(\omega t)] + kx(0)\ e^{- \gamma t} \cos(\omega t) = 0$$

When you solve it further, you will get this equation:
$$[m(\gamma^2 - \omega^2) - 2m \gamma^2 + k]e^{-\gamma \omega t}\cos{\omega t} = 0$$
or
$$[k - m(\gamma^2 + \omega^2)]e^{-\gamma \omega t}\cos{\omega t} = 0$$
This is the condition that should be satisfied for $x(t)$ to be a solution of the equation. What does this mean? This means that this particular complex exponential should be 0.

The factor $\cos{\omega t}$ becomes 0 when $\omega t = (2n+1) \frac{\pi}{2}$

The factor $e^{-\gamma \omega t} = 0$ when $\gamma \omega t$ becomes infinitely large.

But the first factor becomes 0 when,
$$k - m(\gamma^2 + \omega^2)=0$$
or
$$\omega^2 = \frac{k}{m} - \gamma^2$$
giving you the result for $\omega$ as
$$\omega = \sqrt{\frac{k}{m} - \gamma^2}$$

In the question it has been given that
$$\gamma^2 \lt \frac{k}{m}$$ which makes your system underdamped and if you see the equation for $\omega$ you will see it will come out as positive. Now, there are lots of things in this, first there is a relation between these oscillations and phasors. Then there are ways to solve this equation involving many techniques. One of the technique has been shared as the answer. You can also have a pole plot analysis for looking at the stability. But from the student's point of view I think this is enough.
PS: You can solve this equation using complex exponentials, and then make the imaginary part as $0$ in the previous answer.
Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Let the solution be $ce^{zt}$ where $c$ and $z$ are complex numbers. The equation turns to

$$c(mz^2+2\gamma mz+k)e^{zt}=0.$$

By solving the quadratic we have

$$z=-\gamma\pm i \sqrt{\frac km-\gamma^2},$$ which gives you $\omega$.

Note that the initial condition $x(0)$ is not sufficient to make the answer unique. You also need a second one, such as $x'(0)$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment on the minus in the exponent. I am not getting the correct answer but $\left(3 \gamma^{2} m \cos{\left (\omega t \right )} - 4 \gamma \omega m \sin{\left (\omega t \right )} - \omega^{2} m \cos{\left (\omega t \right )} + k x e^{\gamma t}\right) e^{- \gamma t}$. Can you see any other error?

Comment: I don't have complex numbers in my question. I don't see how this is answering the question.